# creating a Dynamic array class in ruby using FFI and C function

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

I would like to create my own dynamic array class in ruby (as a training).
The idea is to have a class DynamicArray that has a capacity (the number of elements it can hold at one given moment), a size (the number of elements that were actually pushed in the array at a given moment) and a static_array which is a static array of ints of a fixed sized. Whenever this static_array is full, we will create a new static array with twice the capacity of the original static_array and copy every elements inside the new static_array.
As there is no static array in ruby, my idea was to use FFI https://github.com/ffi/ffi. to create a function in c that creates a static array of int of size n  then be able to use it in my ruby program.
I have very little knowledge in C and am having a hard time understanding the doc of FFI
Here's what I have so far, a create_array.c file that defines my c function to create an array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * createArray ( int size )
{
  int array[size];
  return 0;

}
```

a create_array.h file (from what I understood of FFI, you need to put your c functions in a c library.):

```
int * createArray ( int size )
```

and this is my dynamic_array.rb file that would do something along this lines :

```
require 'ffi'
class DynamicArray
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib "./create_array.h"
  attach_function :create_array, [:int], :int
  def initialize
    @size = 0
    @capacity = 1
    @current_index = 0
    @static_array = create_array(@capacity)
  end

  def add(element)
    @size += 1
    resize_array if @size > @capacity
    @static_array[@current_index] = element
    @current_index += 1
  end

  private

  def resize_array
    @capacity = @capacity*2
    new_arr = create_array(@capacity)
    @static_array.each_with_index do |val, index|
      new_arr[index] = val
    end
    @static_array = new_arr
  end
end
```

Here are some tests for add and resize :

```
  def test_add
    dynamic_arr = DynamicArray.new
    dynamic_arr.add(1)
    dynamic_arr.add(2)
    assert_equal(1, dynamic_arr.static_array[0])
    assert_equal(2, dynamic_arr.static_array[1])
  end

  def test_resize_array
    dynamic_arr = DynamicArray.new
    dynamic_arr.add(1)
    dynamic_arr.add(2)
    assert_equal(2, dynamic_arr.capacity)
    dynamic_arr.resize_array
    assert_equal(4, dynamic_arr.capacity)
    assert_equal
  end
```

Can you please explain me what I should do to make this work ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good use case, but so that we might more clearly understand what your code is trying to do, can you write some unit tests for your methods?

Comment: Basically my dynamic array class is doubling the array capacity whenever the array (A) is full. So add is adding an element to A. Resize_array is creating a new static array with twice the capacity of A. It then copies all elements from A in the new_arr and the affects new_arr to A. create_array is the C function that is creating a static_array of n elements of type integer. I would like to import create_array into my ruby program thanks to FFI

Comment: @lacostenycoder I tried to add more info, please tell me if it's still unclear

Comment: @DavidGeismar You're trying to use a header file with `ffi_lib`. Instead, you need to pass a shared library with the function.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use FFI (I don't clearly understand what that is BTW); what you could do is sub-class Array and add/overide functions to suit the requirements for DynamicArray !??

Comment: @JL2210 when I try to directly pass the .c file I get LoadError: Could not open library './create_array.c': dlopen(./create_array.c, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 ./create_array.c: file too short

Comment: That's because it's a C source file you're trying to `dlopen()`. You need to compile it into a shared library first: `gcc -shared -fPIC create_array.c -o libcreate_array.so`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you are not working with the C code properly.

In `create_array` C function:

- you are not returning the array, so there's no way the ruby code will work with the newly created array, you need to return it
- if you want to return an array you actually need to return it's pointer
- In C, in order to create an array and the size is not known before compilation you need to allocate it's memory with `malloc` (or some other function in the `alloc`family)

to put it all together, this is how your `create_array.c` file would look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* in order to use malloc */

int * create_array (int size){
  int *a = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  return a; /* returning the pointer to the array a*/
}
```

and your header file `create_array.h`:

```
int * create_array(int);
```

and to wrap everything up you still need to compile it before ruby can touch it:

```sh
gcc -shared -o create_array.so -fPIC create_array.c
```

this command is using gcc to compile your C code into a shared library called `create_array.so` from `create_array.c` source file. gcc needs to be installed for this to work.

Finally you can use the C function in ruby, with some modifications in your `dynamic_array.rb`:

```rb
require 'ffi'
class DynamicArray
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib "./create_array.so" # using the shared lib
  attach_function :create_array, [:int], :pointer # receiving a pointer to the array
  # rest of your code
```

Now, this should work!
But there are still some issues with your ruby code:

- when you do `@static_array = create_array(@capacity)` you are receiving a C pointer to the allocated array, not the array itself, not at least in ruby.
- writing `@static_array[@current_index] = element` will not work `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for #<FFI::Pointer address=0x000055d50e798600>`
- If you want to add an element to the array, C code must do it. Something like:

```
void add_to_array (int * array, int index, int number){
  array[index] = number;
}
```

```rb
attach_function :add_to_array, [:pointer, :int, :int], :void
add_to_array(@static_array, @current_index, element)
```

- Same goes for the `@static_array.each_with_index` you need to code this in C.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer so far. I have taken a quite similar approach but I decided not to implement an add_to_array function in C. What I chose to do is to implement a StaticArray class in ruby which uses the FFIPointer returned from the create_array C function. The FFIPointer class https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Pointer has a couple of methods like read and write that actually perform what your add_to_array function is doing

Comment: Please note, and array of `int` might not be what you want. Such an array can hold numbers (up to a certain point), but it can't safely accommodate Ruby objects (use `VALUE`, `uintptr_t` or `void *` for that).

Answer (score 1):

The following function in your question does **not** allocate the Array you want:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * createArray ( int size )
{
  int array[size];
  return 0;

}
```

The array object in the function you wrote is allocated automatically on the stack and it's destroyed automatically once the function returns. In fact, because it's left unused, the C compiler will probably optimize the array away.

What you were, probably, hoping to do was:

```
VALUE * create_array(size_t size) {
   VALUE * a = calloc(size, sizeof(*a));
   return a;
}
```

Now, the returned `a` is a an array of `VALUE` (or, technically, a pointer to the first member of the array).

`VALUE` is the C equivalent of a Ruby Object (usually this will map to a tagged pointer converted to `unsigned long`).

A resizing could use `realloc`, which automatically copies the existing data to the new memory (or array):

```
VALUE * tmp = realloc(tmp, new_size * sizeof(*a));
if(!tmp) {
   /* deal with error, print message, whatever... */
   free(a);
   exit(-1);
}
a = tmp;
```

You still need to connect the C code to the Ruby layer with the FFI, but this should answer your question about how to resize an array (and fix your mistake about creating one).

**Note**: For big allocations, realloc could optimize away the copying stage, which is very beneficial in large arrays and has a significant positive performance impact. This can be performed by leveraging the fact that memory addresses are virtual and don't have to map to continuous memory segments. i.e., the same memory page could receive a new address as part of a new allocation.